# Session destroyed on page redirect

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, session

I am developing a plugin where I have started a session on init hook.
I have a form which when submit calls a function which uses SDK (i.e payment is handled here). 
If this function returns FALSE then I need to redirect user to the previous page (or given URL) where I need the values stored in the session earlier. But when I try call them, I get none. It seems as if session is getting unset.

Can any one help me on this?

The below function handles the SDK part which either returns true or false.

```
function authorize_net_payment_process($order_metas)
{
    $options = get_option('wp_travel_engine_settings', true);
    $pno = $_SESSION['travelers'];
    $errors = '';
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['authorize']['card_number'] ) || $_POST['authorize']['card_number'] == '' ) {
        $errors = __( 'You must enter a card number', 'wte-authorize-net');
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['authorize']['card_name'] ) || $_POST['authorize']['card_name'] == '' ) {
        $errors = __( 'You must enter the name on your card', 'wte-authorize-net');
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['authorize']['card_exp_month'] ) || $_POST['authorize']['card_exp_month'] == '' ) {
        $errors = __( 'You must enter an expiration month', 'wte-authorize-net');
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['authorize']['card_exp_year'] ) || $_POST['authorize']['card_exp_year'] == '' ) {
        $errors = __( 'You must enter an expiration year', 'wte-authorize-net');
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['authorize']['card_cvc'] ) || $_POST['authorize']['card_cvc'] == '' || strlen( $_POST['authorize']['card_cvc'] ) < 3 )
    {
        $errors = __( 'You must enter a valid CVC', 'wte-authorize-net' );
    }

    if ( ! $errors || $errors=='' ) {
        require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php' );
        $transaction = new AuthorizeNetAIM( $options['authorize_api_id'], $options['authorize_transaction_key'] );
        $card_names = explode( ' ', $_POST['authorize']['card_name'] );
        $first_name = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['fname'];
        $last_name = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['lname'];

        $transaction->amount      = $_SESSION['trip-cost'];
        $transaction->card_num    = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['authorize']['card_number'] ) );
        $transaction->card_code   = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['authorize']['card_cvc'] ) );
        $transaction->exp_date    = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['authorize']['card_exp_month'] ) ) . '/' . strip_tags( trim($_POST['authorize']['card_exp_year'] ) );

        $transaction->first_name  = $first_name;
        $transaction->last_name   = $last_name;

        $transaction->address     = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['address'];
        $transaction->city        = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['city'];
        $transaction->country     = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['country'];
        $transaction->email       = $_POST['wp_travel_engine_booking_setting']['place_order']['booking']['email'];

        $cost = $_SESSION['trip-cost'];
        $cost = str_replace(',', '', $cost);
        $response = $transaction->authorizeAndCapture();
        if ( $response->approved ) {
```

If false is returned then user is redirected to the previous page where he/she puts the values again as previous one was returned false by the above function.

I need the $_SESSION inside that function again (user submits the form again in case of false after redirection).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about PHP sessions or WordPress user sessions using cookies? Please be a bit more specific and append any code you use to accomplish this.

Comment: Its php sessions using $_SESSION. And I am editing my question to  put some of my codes. @swissspidy

Comment: And you're running `session_start()` on `init`? Have you tried running that directly, without hooking into an action?